# Getting Data truncation: when trying to update a datetime string in ISO 8601 format

Tags: mysql

The table `A` contains the field `purchasedate` which is of type `varchar` and contains values with ISO 8601 format for example `2024-03-07T20:18:10Z`. I now try to update this value by subtracting one hour

To do this I try the following:

```
UPDATE A
SET purchasedate = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CONVERT(purchasedate, DATETIME), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ')
WHERE year = '2024';
```

When I execute the query I get this message: `[22001][1292] Data truncation: Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2024-02-07T14:38:06Z'`

On the other hand, in case it is relevant, when doing a `SELECT` query I get the expected results

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CONVERT(purchasedate, DATETIME), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ') AS new_date
FROM A
WHERE year = '2024' order by date_entered desc limit 10;
```

Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix this by using the STR_TO_DATE function to explicitly specify the input format of the varchar date string.
Below is an updated version of your UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE A
SET purchasedate = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(purchasedate, '%Y-%m- 
%dT%H:%i:%sZ'), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ')
WHERE year = '2024';
```

This will help prevent the data truncation issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's datetime format doesn't support the trailing 'Z' of the ISO format.

```
mysql> select date('2024-02-07T14:38:06Z');
+------------------------------+
| date('2024-02-07T14:38:06Z') |
+------------------------------+
| 2024-02-07                   |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                    |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2024-02-07T14:38:06Z' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you strip the last 'Z' it works without triggering a warning:

```
mysql> select date(trim(trailing 'Z' from '2024-02-07T14:38:06Z'));
+------------------------------------------------------+
| date(trim(trailing 'Z' from '2024-02-07T14:38:06Z')) |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 2024-02-07                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I suggest you store datetime values using MySQL native `DATETIME` type, not `VARCHAR`.